# Can I run unreal engine 5 on my laptop? Below are the specifications

Tags: game-engine, game-development, unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit

My laptop specifications:

1. Navida GeForce 840m graphic card
2. 12Gb ram
3. intel i5 processor
   4.15.6 inch screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to "Run" the editor, edit Blueprint Graphs and create simple levels without complex shaders, materials and with low amount of assets

but it will be really hard to do anything more espessially, if you wanna dig into C++ with Visual Studio

Just download UE5 via epic launcher and check it.
Remember to install Unreal on SSD if you have one. Same deal goes with projects.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think that you can, but expect it to be very slow, especially when the shaders are compiling.